# fork() doesn't create grandchild

Tags: c, fork

I want to use fork() to create a child that continues create another child (grandchild of the parent process). But I cannot seem to create a grandchild with this code. Is there anything wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void child_A_proc()
{
  while (1)
  {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", "A");
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}

void parent_proc()
{
  while (1)
  {
    write(1, "B", 1);
  }
}

void child_of_child_A_proc() 
{
  while (1)
  {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", "C");
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  if (fork() == 0){
    child_A_proc();
    if (fork() == 0)
      child_of_child_A_proc();
    else 
      child_A_proc();
  }
  else
    parent_proc();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is output of the program right now? I suspect the problem is about concur writing rather then fork(). Try to write to a different files (instead of stdout) to make sure problem is in fork

Comment: The ouput are only A and B. No C appears

Comment: You should always use braces with control statements, otherwise you'll run into major problems like OpenSSL did: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/

Answer (score 3):

Check for calling functions that do not return.

```
  if (fork() == 0){
    child_A_proc();
    /* unreachable */
    if (fork() == 0)
      child_of_child_A_proc();
    else 
      child_A_proc();
  }
```

Comment: Oh yeah ur right. I moved the child_A_proc() to else in the inner if now. It works